# How to read npz file using NumSharp, when a npz file contain different data types

Tags: numsharp

`.npz` file contains two npy files, `faces.npy` and `neighbors.npy`.

- `faces.npy` is `float64`, shape is 12*15
- `neighbors.npy` is `int64`, shape is 12*3

First try:
Type is `double[,]`, but neighbors is null

```
var npz = np.Load_Npz<double[,]>(@"D:\dnns\ifcnet\test\wall\IFCWALL.43.npz");
var faces = npz["faces.npy"];
var neighbors = npz["neighbors.npy"];
```

Second try:
Type is `Int64[,]`, but faces is null

```
var npz = np.Load_Npz<In[,]>(@"D:\dnns\ifcnet\test\wall\IFCWALL.43.npz");
var faces = npz["faces.npy"];
var neighbors = npz["neighbors.npy"];
```

Third try:
Read faces by `double[,]`, and read neighbors by `Int64[,]`, but when reading the same file, another process uses the file!

```
var npz = np.Load_Npz<double[,]>(@"D:\dnns\ifcnet\test\wall\IFCWALL.43.npz");
var faces = npz["faces.npy"];
var npz2 = np.Load_Npz<Int64[,]>(@"D:\dnns\ifcnet\test\wall\IFCWALL.43.npz");
var neighbors= npz2["neighbors.npy"];
```

Answer (score 0):

My speculation is that loading NPZ with multiple type is not supported.

My approach to this problem is to load NPZ file as `ZipArchive`, then open the stream, then feed it to the `load` function.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)))
{
    Stream transStream = archive.GetEntry("trans.npy").Open();
    NDArray npyContent = np.load(transStream);
}
```

Notice that I use `load` instead of `Load<T>`. This way, you can load multiple types of arrays without prior knowledge of the array.

Note: `Load<float[,]>` fails with some random files, but `load` worked reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var npz = np.Load_Npz<Array>(@"D:\dnns\ifcnet\test\wall\IFCWALL.43.npz");
var faces = npz["faces.npy"];
var neighbors = npz["neighbors.npy"];
```

This returns `NpzDictionary<T>` (or `NpzDictionary<Array>`), which your `npz["faces.npy"]` will then convert to an `[,]` array.